# SQL Server Multiple Cumulative Sums (2012 or later)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read a few posts on here about cumulative sums, however I've been struggling with `SUM OVER` or other cumulative sums that join the same data using <= as part of inner join so I'm looking for some clarification.

I have the following columns from my financial data:

```
AccountID,
FiscalYear,
FiscalQuarter,
FiscalPeriod,
PeriodType (we report on calendar and fiscal periods),
CurrencyType (source or functional currency),
DataSet (actual or budgeted data),
Currency (the currency of the transaction,
PeriodAmount
```

This information is currently summed by period in row format, so I union the data together to get it in tabular format and then attempt to get running totals by period for cumulative quarter and year. For example:

If my data is (for now I'm assuming the currency and other fields not apearring are the same, but they will vary):

```
ACCTID FYear FQuarter FPeriod PAmount
123    2015  1        1       $100
123    2015  1        2       $100
123    2015  1        3       $100
123    2015  2        4       $100
```

The results I want for my data should be:

```
123, 2015, 1, 1, $100, $100 (cumulative quarter), $100 (cumulative year)
123, 2015, 1, 2, $100, $200 (cumulative quarter), $200 (cumulative year)
123, 2015, 1, 3, $100, $300 (cumulative quarter), $300 (cumulative year)
123, 2015, 2, 4, $100, $100 (cumulative quarter), $400 (cumulative year)
```

It seems as thought when I do `SUM OVER(PARTITION BY AccountID, FYear, FQuarter)` I get $300 for each result for quarter 1 or when I `SUM OVER(PARTITION BY AccountID, FYear)` I always get $400 for each record.

I'm doing this on a million plus records so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) Over (Partition BY FiscalQuarter Order BY FiscalQuarter)
FROM Table_name
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your code else code only answer doesn't suffice much.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
SELECT ACCTID, FYear, FQuarter, FPeriod, PAmount,
       SUM(PAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCTID, FYear, FQuarter 
                          ORDER BY FPeriod) AS rtQuarter,
       SUM(PAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCTID, FYear 
                          ORDER BY FPeriod) AS rtYear
FROM mytable
```

What determines a running total in an `OVER` clause is `ORDER BY`.

Hence, the first running total returned by the above query, i.e. `rtQuarter`, is calculated within each `ACCTID, FYear, FQuarter` slice. As long as `FQuarter` value changes running total is reset.

The second running total, i.e. `rtYear`, is calculated per `ACCTID, FYear`. `PAmount` value adds up as `FPeriod` increases.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83e1f/3)

Comment: The partition by works fine, but as soon as I add in the order by it gives me an incorrect syntax near 'order' error message. I'm using SQL server 2012 version 11.0.5058.0. I'm sure there's no issue in my query because as soon as I remove the order by it works.

Comment: Ah I see now though that the compatibility level is 2005 90

Comment: @Ian But you mention '2012 or later' in the subject of your question.

Comment: I agree and that's my mistake ... I thought it was on the latest compatibility myself. So, I apologize and now this takes a different turn because I can't do what I'd been attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

you missed a part of your `OVER`clause. in order to calculate a cumulative total you need to add an order by:

```
SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY AccountID, FYear ORDER BY FQuarter, FPeriod )
```